# VS2010 debugger fails on a static std::forward_list, any work around?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, stl

With a static std::forward_list, the debugger only shows the 1'st element.

A non static std::forward_list or a static std::list works fine.

Is there any work around in the debugger I could use?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <forward_list>
#include <list>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    static std::forward_list<int> sfl;
    sfl.push_front( 1 ); 
    sfl.push_front( 2 );

    std::forward_list<int> fl;
    fl.push_front( 1 ); 
    fl.push_front( 2 );

    static std::list<int> sl;
    sl.push_front( 1 ); 
    sl.push_front( 2 );

    //Break here.
    //In a debugger watch window:
    //  'sfl' only shows the '2' element
    //  'fl' & 'sl' shows all elements.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in Visual Studio's debugger visualizer.  The closest thing to a workaround I've come up with is to modify the `forward_list` entry in `autoexp.dat` (normally found in `%VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\Packages\Debugger\`)

The file should have a section with the following:

```
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;  std::forward_list from <forward_list>
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
std::forward_list<*>{
    preview (
        #(
            "(",
            #list(
                head: $e._Myhead,
                next: _Next
            ) : $e._Myval,
            ")"
        )
    )

    children (
        #list(
            head: $e._Myhead,
            next: _Next
        ) : $e._Myval
    )
}
```

Replace with:

```
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;  std::forward_list from <forward_list>
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
std::forward_list<*>{
    preview (
        #(
            "(",
            #(
                $e._Myhead->_Myval,
                ",",
                #list(
                    head: $e._Myhead->_Next,
                    next: _Next
                ) : $e._Myval,
            ),
            ")"
        )
    )

    children (
        #(
            [actual 0]: $e._Myhead->_Myval,
            #list(
                head: $e._Myhead->_Next,
                next: _Next
            ) : $e._Myval
        )
    )
}
```

This is not a great solution.  It displays the children as `[actual 0], [0], [1], ...` rather than `[0], [1], [2], ...`, i.e. element `x` is labelled `[x-1]`.

You can however modify `autoexp.dat` without closing Visual Studio, you just need to restart the debugger.  So I'd recommend using this hack for just as long as you need to debug a particular issue, and then revert back to the original `autoexp.dat`.